# Normal Mixer vs Joyo RockHouse/JamHub

Tags: rehearsal

I have an instrumental trio with E-Drum, guitar and bass.
Due to the fact that I have some neighbors near to my house, we are forced to make a silent rehearsal. Next Saturday will be our first attempt.

I have a TASCAM US-16X8 audio interface which I think is big enough in terms of input, but I'm wondering if I would be able to send a unique stereo mix to 3 of those 8 output channels. It's probably is possible, but I don't know.

I have seen that most people that perform silent rehearsals choose to buy a dedicated component like Joyo Rockhouse or JamHub, but by being in Argentina, these two products are not available to me.

However, I am wondering what's the difference between theses devices and other mixers out there; can I buy a normal mixer such as a Behringer Xenyx or something similar in order to be able to hear a custom mix in the best of the cases? Is there any budget friendly option to solve my problem?

Sorry, I'm a bit lost with these kind of configurations that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yeah, the JamHub was really neat for these situations. Too bad it isn't made anymore!

Comment: With only three instruments, it really shouldn't be necessary to need three different mixes. Especially for rehearsals. We should all be capable of playing with two others and producing a decent mix between them all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for a start you'll have to send your 3 stereo mixes to SIX of those output channels, configured as three stereo pairs.

I don't think the supplied Settings Panel software is powerful enough to do what you want by itself.   But software like the Control Room feature in Cubase will be able to.
You'll need some headphone amplifiers too.

But why do you need three different mixes?  Take the single headphone output of the US-16X8 into a simple headphone amplifier with at least three outputs. Choose one with a volume control for each output.   A 'more me' mix doesn't really help anyone play more musically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Laurence. Do you think that a regular mixer provides power for headphones? One of the ones that I have is 80 ohms, so I guess that I would need some phantom power, is that correct?

Comment: The need of different mixes comes by thinking that probably each one wants to hear more presence of its own instrument, but it would be in the best of the cases, I'm fine with the same one for the three of us.

Comment: A regular mixer supplies ONE stereo headphone output (and so does your US-16X8).   Additional monitor mixes will be Line level and require a headphone amplifier.   This has nothing to do with phantom power, which is a microphone thing.  I've expanded my answer.